# How to make a timer in java which let's change the color?

Tags: java, timer

I am making a system for trafic lights in Java.
Now, I can push on three bottons to change the color of the light and this works perfectly.

How can I make a 20-secods-timer, where it starts with a green light. Afther 5 seconds it changes to orange for 2 seconds, and the last 13 seconds it becomes red. When the timer is finished, it needs to restart from the beginning.

Hopefully somebody can help me

greetings,

Samuel

```js
package javacursus;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SEE extends Applet
{   
    
  // Begin variabelen
  boolean rood;
  boolean oranje;
  boolean groen;
  private Button roodKnop = new Button();
  private Button oranjeKnop = new Button();
  private Button groenKnop = new Button();
  // Einde variabelen
  
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        // De achtergrond\





        // Het stoplicht
        Color bruin = new Color(110,75,40);
        g.setColor(bruin);
        g.fillRect(140, 20, 60, 150);
        g.fillRect(160, 150, 20, 80);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(150,25,40,40);
        g.fillOval(150,75,40,40);
        g.fillOval(150,125,40,40);
        if (rood)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(150, 25, 40, 40);
        }
        if (oranje)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillOval(150, 75, 40, 40);
        }
        if (groen)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(150, 125, 40, 40);
        }
        
    }
    
    
   public void init()
   {
     setLayout(null);
     setSize(400,400);
     roodKnop.setBounds(20, 300, 75, 25);
     roodKnop.setBackground(Color.red);
     roodKnop.setLabel("rood");
     add(roodKnop);
     roodKnop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        roodKnop_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    
     oranjeKnop.setBounds(120, 300, 75, 25);
     oranjeKnop.setBackground(Color.orange);
     oranjeKnop.setLabel("oranje");
     add(oranjeKnop);
     oranjeKnop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         oranjeKnop_ActionPerformed(evt);
       }
     });

     groenKnop.setBounds(220, 300, 75, 25);
     groenKnop.setLabel("groen");
     groenKnop.setBackground(Color.green);
     groenKnop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         groenKnop_ActionPerformed(evt);
       }
     });
    add(groenKnop);
    }

  public void roodKnop_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    rood=true;
    groen=false;
    oranje=false;
    repaint();
  }

  public void oranjeKnop_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    rood=false;
    groen=false;
    oranje=true;
    repaint();
  }

  public void groenKnop_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    rood=false;
    groen=true;
    oranje=false;
    repaint();
  }

}
```

Comment: You're mixing Swing and AWT.  Consider looking at JApplet, JButton, etc.  This doesn't really affect what you're doing here, it's just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a Timer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a task every 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).  They trigger an event listener after a specified delay, so you won't need to alter your code too much.

For example, take your orange button action listener and make it a variable instead of a method.  This allows it to be used by the button as well as the timer.

```
private final ActionListener orangeListener = e -> {
    rood=false;
    groen=false;
    oranje=true;
    repaint();
}
```

In init, your orange button receives the action listener:

```
oranjeKnop.addActionListener(orangeListener);
```

Wherever you decide to trigger the timer event from, the same thing applies:

```
new TimerTask(2000, orangeListener)
```

will cause the orange listener to fire after 2 seconds.  I guess you will do this from within other action listeners, so for example your orange listener then becomes

```
private final ActionListener orangeListener = e -> {
    rood=false;
    groen=false;
    oranje=true;
    new TimerTask(2000, redListener).start();
    repaint();
}
```

When the light becomes orange, it will automatically become red 2 seconds later.